# How to apply middleware to gorilla/mux routes

Tags: rest, go, middleware, roles

I have this main function in a main.go file inside the main directory

```
func main() {
    log.Printf("Server started")

    router := sw.NewRouter()
    manager := manage.NewDefaultManager()
    manager.SetAuthorizeCodeTokenCfg(manage.DefaultAuthorizeCodeTokenCfg)

    manager.MustTokenStorage(store.NewMemoryTokenStore())

    clientStore := store.NewClientStore()
    manager.MapClientStorage(clientStore)

    srv := server.NewDefaultServer(manager)
    srv.SetAllowGetAccessRequest(true)
    srv.SetClientInfoHandler(server.ClientFormHandler)
    manager.SetRefreshTokenCfg(manage.DefaultRefreshTokenCfg)

    srv.SetInternalErrorHandler(func(err error) (re *errors.Response) {
        log.Println("Internal Error:", err.Error())
        return
    })

    srv.SetResponseErrorHandler(func(re *errors.Response) {
        log.Println("Response Error:", re.Error.Error())
    })

    router.HandleFunc("/oauth2/token", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        srv.HandleTokenRequest(w, r)
    })

    router.HandleFunc("/credentials", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        clientId := uuid.New().String()[:8]
        clientSecret := uuid.New().String()[:8]
        err := clientStore.Set(clientId, &models.Client{
            ID:     clientId,
            Secret: clientSecret,
            Domain: "http://localhost:9094",
        })
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err.Error())
        }

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(map[string]string{"CLIENT_ID": clientId, "CLIENT_SECRET": clientSecret})
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000", router))
}
```

The functions below are in different files in the sub directory of the main as

*maindir
    *subdir

//Funtion in handler.go in subdir

```
func protecteduri(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Write([]byte("Hello, I'm protected"))
}
```

//This function in middleware.go in subdir

```
func validateToken(f http.HandlerFunc, srv *server.Server) http.HandlerFunc {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        _, err := srv.ValidationBearerToken(r)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
            return
        }

        f.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}
```

And my routes are in the router.go in the subdir as

```
type Route struct {
    Name        string
    Method      string
    Pattern     string
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc
}

type Routes []Route

func NewRouter() *mux.Router {
    router := mux.NewRouter().StrictSlash(true)
    for _, route := range routes {
        var handler http.Handler
        handler = route.HandlerFunc
        handler = Logger(handler, route.Name)

        router.
            Methods(route.Method).
            Path(route.Pattern).
            Name(route.Name).
            Handler(handler)
    }

    return router
}

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello World!")
}

var routes = Routes{
    {
        "Index",
        "GET",
        "/",
        Index,
    },

    {
        "protecteduri",
        strings.ToUpper("Get"),
        "/protected",
        protecteduri,
    },
}
```

My question is how do i apply the "validateToken" function (middleware) to the routes in the router.go?
The function is to validate the access token in the request message before calling the handler functions.

I have modify the middleware to the below but it only work if the handler function "/protected" is in the main function.
I have many handlers and do not want to put all of them in the main.go.

```
func ValidateToken(srv *server.Server) func(http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return func(next http.Handler) http.Handler {
        return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            notAuth := []string{"/oauth2/token", "/credentials"} //List of endpoints that doesn't require auth
            requestPath := r.URL.Path                            //current request path

            //check if request does not need authentication, serve the request if it doesn't need it
            for _, value := range notAuth {

                if value == requestPath {
                    next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
                    return
                }
            }
            _, err := srv.ValidationBearerToken(r)
            if err != nil {
                http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
                return
            }

            next.ServeHTTP(w, r)
        })
    }
}
```